# How to install texconfig-sys?

Tags: installing

On macOS 14, I try to configure auto-multiple-choice but it needs `texconfig-sys` to be installed.

As I installed BasicTex with Homebrew, it does not include `texconfig-sys`. I wonder if it is possible to install a package or a set of tools which includes `texconfig-sys`, or if I need to install a more complete LaTeX installation.

Which `tlmgr` package or `brew` contains `texconfig-sys` ? Or is it possible to install it by downloading/extracting/compiling it, and how ?

Comment: Instead of using the homebrew version, you could give vanilla texlive a try: https://tug.org/texlive/